# How do I find the limit of the recursive sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a sequence that is defined recursively by $a_1=1, a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_n}$ and it is increasing for $n>1$ and bounded above.

How would I find the limit to the recursive sequence?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2109602/42969